# Band or artist that has more songs appear on movie soundtrack

Tags: soundtrack, appearance

What group or artist holds the record for appearing on the most movie soundtracks?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's Jimi Hendrix. At least according to [this](http://www.billboard.com/photos/6450981/most-overplayed-songs-in-movies/1) website, 'All Along The Watchtower' holds the record in appearing in most movies. If you also count the other great songs of Jimi that were used in movies, I bet he holds the record.

Also I would consider placing Felix Mendelssohn at #1 place because who would argue that the song that holds the record in appearing in most movies is the 'Wedding March'?